# Insert values database without change the page

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I want to insert a message in a DB but the page need to be the same.

How do I do?

PS: Thanks so much for your help

Comment: Use AJAX. Have a search around. There's literally thousands of tutorials and questions covering how to do it.

Comment: Here's a link https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/.